# Complex root of a number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let us suppose I have a number $x$ such that $x<0$. If I want to write the roots of the $x^{1/n}$. How can we write the roots of this number. I thought we can write

$$|x|^{1/n}e^{i\pi\theta}$$ for $\theta = \frac{2l + 1}{n}$ and $l = 0,1,2$ etc.

Is this correct ?

Similary If I wanted to write $x^{m/n}$, I should I write

$$|x|^{m/n}e^{mi\pi\theta}$$ for $\theta = \frac{2l + 1}{n}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

What you have seems okay but i think $\theta$ in your case might be alittle off.

One way of doing this is through De Moivre's theorem, here it is:

$$|x|^\frac{1}{n}(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta))^{\frac{1}{n}}=|x|^{\frac{1}{n}}[cos(\frac{2k\pi + \theta}{n})+isin(\frac{2k\pi + \theta}{n})]$$

Where $k=0,1,2,3...,n-1$

So all your doing here is converting your complex number to polar form and applying De Moivre's theorem.

And then if you really need it in your form you can take the argument out of the trig form and use it in your form.

Im new to answering questions so any feedback is welcome thanks :)